# rsync unable to copy folder that has name with spaces

Tags: bash, shell, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to copy folders from one place to another. Some of folder names have spaces and some have alphanumeric names. The problem that i am having is that when i iterate through the folders that are named with spaces e.g. - `temp 123` then rsync is splitting this name into `temp` and `123`throwing an error.

Below are some of the sample folder names that i have -

```
W4F (CS DP)
temp 123
KNOWLEDGE; LIB
USA-12
```

Below is my loop along with rsync command

```
 for f in [A-Z0-9]*;
 do
 rsync -rvcm --include='A60_*xml' --include='*/' --exclude='*' $f /Temp/ 
 done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing $f with double quotes.

```
 rsync -rvcm --include='A60_*xml' --include='*/' --exclude='*' "$f" /Temp/
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked without any issues